# App is crashing when I try to send intent to another activity (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-listview

Whenever I try to go to another activity, the app is crashing. Here is my source code:

Main.Java

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // storing string resources into Array
        String[] adobe_products ;
        adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,R.id.weekofday, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              // selected item
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });

    }
}
```

SingleListItem.java

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.row);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtProduct2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label2);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = (String) i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);
        txtProduct.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        if(product.equals("Odilo Globocnik"))
        {
            txtProduct2.setText(R.string.Odilo_Globocnik);
            txtProduct2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else if (product.equals("Josef Kramer"))
        {
            txtProduct2.setText(R.string.Josef_Kramer);
            txtProduct2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else if (product.equals("Paul Blobel"))
        {
            txtProduct2.setText(R.string.Paul_Blobel);
            txtProduct2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else if (product.equals("Friedrich Jeckeln"))
        {
            txtProduct2.setText(R.string.Friedrich_Jeckeln);
            txtProduct2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

    }
}
```

Row.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/weekofday"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Singleitemlist.xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_label2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The manifest has:

```
<activity android:name=".SingleListItem"
                    android:label="Single Item Selected">

        </activity>
```

LogCat:

```
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at com.example.booktest.Main.onCreate(Main.java:20)
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1617)
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    ... 11 more
12-30 23:15:35.189: W/dalvikvm(19093): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)


12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at com.example.booktest.Main$1.onItemClick(Main.java:40)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3737)
12-30 23:15:35.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19093):
```

I know that my variables names are bad. I will change them as soon as possible.

EDIT: New CatLog:

```
12-30 23:51:19.759: E/AndroidRuntime(19744): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 23:51:19.759: E/AndroidRuntime(19744):    at com.example.booktest.SingleListItem.onCreate(SingleListItem.java:22)
12-30 23:51:19.759: E/AndroidRuntime(19744):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-30 23:51:19.759: E/AndroidRuntime(19744):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1617)
12-30 23:51:19.759: E/AndroidRuntime(19744):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
    at com.example.booktest.Main$1.onItemClick(Main.java:40)
```

Your app crashes here:

```
String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

because `view` is a LinearLayout not a TextView. Try:

```
String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.weekOfDay)).getText().toString();
```

---

**Addition**
You can see this is a different LogCat, the problem here is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.booktest.SingleListItem.onCreate(SingleListItem.java:22)
```

If you look at SingleListItem on line 22 you'll find:

```
txtProduct.setText(product);
```

So `txtProduct` is null. This means that `findViewById(R.id.title)` couldn't locate any Views in yor layout with the id `@+id/title`. Let's look at what view you are loading:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.row);
```

Hmm, `row.xml` doesn't have a TextView for `title` (or `product_label2.xml`). You loaded the wrong layout, use:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.singleitemlist);
```

---

Now I cannot walk you through every step of debugging your app. But from my advice above, you should understand how to read your LogCat. The stack trace (LogCat errors) will lead your straight to the problem.

Please click the check mark to accept this answer as the solution to your original question and if you just cannot solve a future error please ask a new question. Good luck! :)

Comment: Still crashing. Thank you for trying.

Comment: Please post the new LogCat errors. First clear your LogCat then run the app again, after it crashes only post the red error lines.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll give you one last tip, if you want to use `main.xml` in your Main class you need to change the ListView's id to `android:id="@android:id/list"` as the LogCats hinted you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sam's answer is 100% correct, you also have another error with your `Main` activity.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
12-30 23:13:55.129: E/AndroidRuntime(19016):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
```

Because you extend ListActivity then the Android code is looking for a ListView with a specific id. You need to change:

main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

to this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

If you understand **how** we arrived at these answers **from your LogCat** that is a very valuable lesson and you will be able to fix many many many more errors yourself in the future before you need to post again :-)

Comment: Thank you Blundell. Good stuff to know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is how you get the `extras` data from the `Intent`.

Try this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   product = extras.getString("product");
}
```

Comment: [`Intent#getStringExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) is shorthand for your code above. But in both cases `getIntent()` could return null so you should check against that.